# What is the meaning of this symbol in a German churchbook?

Tags: germany, church-records

This is from a church book from the Thuringia region.  The priests often marked deaths with a cross symbol, and in more recent years, also a reference to the entry for that death.

[image]

However, I notice that both of the children of a distant ancestor of mine have a somewhat different mark.  These entries would have been added in different years, and I've not seen it on other entries near either record, so it doesn't look like it was just a stylistic difference, yet it's pretty clearly the same mark for each.

[image]

Does anyone know what this "up arrow" version of the cross could be indicating?  I've not found the death entry for one of the two, but for the one I do know, she moved to a different town nearby, and died there; my only guess is that perhaps it's indicating a death that didn't occur in this town?

Edit: These symbols don't appear to match the "Common" symbols handout from family search.  The same 5 symbols appear constantly, and always on the left by the entry #:

[image]

1. Nota Bene https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene
2. Deceased, sometimes with a year, and sometimes later on, with the # of the death register's matching entry.
3. ? (this question)
4. ?
5. A { bracket, joins several entries that took place at the same time

note: marriage notations look similar to "deceased" notations, but without a symbol, and indicated on the right side margin.  Confirmation notations occur occasionally, also on the right side, though not very often.  Those are without an entry #, only a year, as there was no equivalent confirmations register book.  Examples in context:

[image]

Comment: can you provide year range please

Comment: The baptism records that carry these are from 1688 and 1696, though I've seen it on a few other scattered (unrelated) records at least through the 1800s.  For the one for whom I have found the death record, the death (and presumably when the mark was added) was in 1752.

Comment: idk if this is the exact/right answer but this [document](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/img_auth.php/0/07/German_Genealogical_Word_List.pdf) at the very bottom indicates the cross just means died, but this isn't the arrow symbol

Comment: Please add the date ranges from your comment into the body of the question.

Comment: These signs could be symbols for each day of the week consisting of the signs used to represent as well planets in our solar system. The signs shown here stand for m Tuesday, the day the person died. You can calculate (or count backwards) the day of death, when you know the day of burying which is usually the day the entry in the church book was made. For example, if the entry was made on a Thursday (checking with a calendar calculator you can find online), then the sign above means the person deceased two days before.

Comment: On the German Wikipedia you find here a nice table for all signs for each weekday: (https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wochentag#Symbole_für_die_Wochentage)

Comment: My first impression was that the cross was doodled on, with no added meaning.What was drawn now looks like a Wegkreuz, that is a [wayside cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayside_cross), with a weather cover, like those seen in many rural areas of Germany. If a particular meaning should be attached, the symbol would appear more frequently.

Comment: I contacted family search and they fixed the broken links on the German Church Record [page](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Germany_Church_Records#Downloadable_Handouts) specifically the Common symbols [handout](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/img_auth.php/4/4e/Common_Symbols_-_Kurrent-german.pdf) download which makes me think death and/or buried

Comment: Could you please add more of the pages?

Comment: Here's another one I found for someone else today, from 1732.  They were interested in entry 7 on the right side.  Perhaps coincidentally, that person also died not in this town (they died in the US).  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_VKye1HQwbTM017Xcc0ikl70Z-6FmTa9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I guess that number 4 means Tuesday. Can you please give the exact date for that corresponding entry, please, or check online with a calendar calculator which day of the week the corresponding date was?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to give us for #3 and 4 the entire entry of a, what you consider, representative entry? I may have an idea, however, I think it might be pure guesswork if not given further details on the entry itself. It is ok if it is in German.

Comment: Sure, here you go; a few example pages.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g7eGdPIePsoyBsBacSbI5V0mWvwqKBRx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: couldn't it be so that it is always the case that the deceased is a child or someone who died as virgin?